# Add different classes to elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to give different Classes to each `<a>`.
I can do it only with js/jquery.

```
<ul class="ulClass">
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

My attempt of giving them Classes (className1, className2, className3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var classNumber = 1;
    var className = "className" + classNumber;
    jQuery(".ulClass:nth-child(1)").addClass(className + classNumber++);
    jQuery(".ulClass:nth-child(2)").addClass(className + classNumber++);
    jQuery(".ulClass:nth-child(3)").addClass(className + classNumber++);
    jQuery(".ulClass:nth-child(4)").addClass(className + classNumber++);
});
```

My code just gives class name to the `ul` element... In addition it is `className11`. What happens wrong here?

Comment: I think the selector should be `.ulClass li:nth-child(n)` instead

Comment: you're concatenating className (resolving to "classname1") and classNumber (resolving to 1). As it's written, your increment won't actually happen. You need to rewrite that portion to: addClass(className + (classNumber++));

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your links with the .each() jQuery method.
[See the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)
This way you can use the index of the current iteration of the loop for your class name.

```
$(".ulClass a").each(function(index){
  $(this).addClass("className" + index);
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: You're right @JayBlanchard but I was on my phone. I will update my answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
  var classNumber = 1;
  $(".ulClass a").each(function(){
    var className = "className" + classNumber;
    $(this).addClass(className);
    classNumber++;

});
```

Comment: i think you meant to put className inside the loop otherwise className will always be equals to "className1". Also i think he needs to add the class to the "li" elements not "a"

Comment: This will add class to anchor tag not the li element :)

Comment: That is what OP asked for

Comment: Well, I didnt even notice that I tried to reach `li` element in my code

Comment: in fact, i hadn't noticed that you were asking for "a" elements but reading the code it looks like you are trying to work on "li" elements

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishtuteja10/4by5dmzv/) here.

In order to have a unique class name for the `<a>` elements in your unordered list. You can iterate over each "a" using `$(".ulClass a").each` and then use `addClass(className)` on the current context `this`.
And since you want the anchor tags to have a unique class name, so I am using a `classNum` variable which increments by 1 after every iteration.

```
var classNum = 1;
$(".ulClass a").each(function(){
    var className = "className" + classNum;
    $(this).addClass(className);
    classNum++;
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.